# IONIC 4 - Routing Navigation

Tags: routes, navigation, ionic4

Good morning dear all,

I'm a beginner with Ionic and I encountered some problems with routing.
As my title is displaying, I encountered some difficulties to make works my navigation in my subfolder.

Does somebody can help me to clarify where I was mistaken.

My tabs pages have also a routing to navigate to dashboard and it's working. But when I reuse the code in my Dashboard pages to navigate to [barcode - report - transaction - help], it doesn't work

[image]

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardPage } from './dashboard.page';

const routes: Routes = [

{
  path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardPage,
    children: [
  {  path: 'barcode', loadChildren: 'barcode/barcode.module#BarcodePageModule' },
  {  path: 'transaction',  loadChildren: 'transaction/transaction.module#TransactionPageModule' },
  {  path: 'report',  loadChildren: 'report/report.module#ReportPageModule'  },
  {  path: 'help', loadChildren: 'help/help.module#HelpPageModule' },  
    ]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/tabs/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardPageRoutingModule {}
```

```
<!-- START CONTENT -->
<ion-content class="dashboardContent">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row >
        <ion-col>
          <div><ion-button routerLink="/barcode"  class="dashboardBtn" color="primary">Barcode Scan</ion-button></div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <div><ion-button routerLink="/transaction" class="dashboardBtn" color="primary">Add Transaction</ion-button></div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <div><ion-button  routerLink="/report" class="dashboardBtn" color="primary">Report</ion-button></div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <div><ion-button  routerLink="/help" class="dashboardBtn" color="primary">Help</ion-button></div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
 <!-- END CONTENT -->
```

And my error is : **Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/dashboard/barcode'**

Thanks per advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question ,if you need to access to your others pages inside help , you need to declare path in app-routing.module.ts

`

```
 { path: 'report', loadChildren: './report/report.module#ReportPageModule' },
```

then do a method inside your help page

`goToReport () {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('reportPage');
}`

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1 & my preferable) You can use the Segments instead of tabs. here is  the link [Segment reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment)

Solution 2 as per your current code) You can have this reference for the tab.
use ion-tab instead of ion-button.

Please follow the link [Tabs reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs)

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your explanations and links. I would like to access to my others pages with these button:

[image]

Can I use tab also, or others solutions ???

Comment: Then you should use to create methods for every button click event.
Like barcode has his own event, same as others.

If you get those dynamically same method with condition and passe click button arg with that method.

If you create sap-rate events then you need like this routing function.

Ts side.
openCart() {
    if (this.count) {
      this.router.navigate(['cart']);// as per your page setup like child or parent you can use it.
    }
  }

HTML side.

 <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="openCart()">
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>

Comment: I tried to add you command line:

the typescript on my dashboard.page.ts
the HTML on my dashboard.page.html

but the button doesn't work and is disable concerning the "click"

Comment: There must be something conditionally work in your code so need to just try without any condition than you can update with your condition based on requirement. Otherwise this works fine in my code currently I'm using the same thing in my code without the data transfer on click. If you want to carry data along with navigation you need to use little different code line.